# .Save() with django redirect

Tags: django, api, templates, save, models

I'm using an API that saves some information to a User profile before redirecting the previous page. It looks something like this:

First, the view that loads 'home/id' in feed.views

```
def home(request, id):
    request.session["next"] = id
    # do stuff to load the page, i.e. adding stuff to context dictionary
    return render_to_response('home/' + id + '.html', context)
```

The view that catches registration with the API:

```
def API(request):
    user = request.user
    # get some info from api here
    user.save() 
    redirect_url = '/home/' + request.session["next"]
    return redirect(redirect_url, permanent=True)
```

The problem: This doesn't save the info to 'user', but still redirects back to 'home/id'. I had tried this before, which actually saved the info for some reason:

```
def API(request):
    user = request.user
    # same stuff
    user.save()
    from feed.views import home
    return home(request, request.session["next"])
```

But this way doesn't change the url back to the previous page, which I need it to do. Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Can you paste more of the code for each view that isn't working. In the first you are calling the `user.save()` and in the second you are not.  Plus you `redirect urls` are different in each, so maybe that is why they are redirecting to different places.

Comment: done, tell me if you need more

Comment: You are missing this in your 2nd API view: `redirect_url = '/home/' + request.session["next"]` and then test with that in your "return" statement.

Comment: That's the exact same thing as my first API view then. I was trying to show that the second API view works in that it saves data to the User, but the first API view does not save data to the User. Look closely, the two return statements are different. One redirects, while the second one calls another view function.

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect(redirect_url, permanent=True)
```

The `permanent` parameter will issue a 301 status code. This tells the browser that this paged is moved permanently. Your browser will save this information, and the next time you request this page, your browser will not even try to get the old page (your `API` view), but will directly load the new url (your `home` view).

To solve this issue, remove the `permanent=True` parameter, and clear your browser cache.

Please *do* use a redirect, instead of returning the result of another view function; failing to do so will cause data to be resend to the server upon reloading the page or pressing the back button in your browser.